# liferay finder method always return null

Tags: java, sql, liferay

My entity:

```
<entity name="Role" local-service="true" remote-service="false">
    <column name="id" type="long" primary="true" />
    <column name="system_id" type="int" />
    <column name="user_id" type="int" />
    <column name="comment" type="String" />
    <column name="status_id" type="int" />
    <column name="create_date" type="Date" />
    <column name="update_date" type="Date" />
    <column name="systemrequest_id" type="int" />
    <order by="asc">
            <order-column name="id" />
    </order>
    <finder name="bySystem" return-type="Collection">
        <finder-column name="system_id"/>
    </finder>
    <finder name="byUser" return-type="Collection">
        <finder-column name="user_id" />
        <finder-column name="status_id" />
    </finder>
    <finder name="byId" return-type="gad">
        <finder-column name="id" />
    </finder>
</entity>
```

Then I have copied the method `findBybyUser()` from `RoleUtil.java` into `RoleLocalServiceImpl.java` like:

```
public java.util.List<com.example.model.gad> findBybyUser(
    int user_id, int status_id) throws com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException {
    return RoleUtil.findBybyUser(user_id, status_id);
}
```

I have deployed the service with `mvn liferay:build-service`

Finally I want to use this finder method inside of `doView` method in my portlet:

```
@Override
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
    List<PersonRoleHelper> personRoleList = new ArrayList<PersonRoleHelper>();
    try {
        List<User> userList = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(1, UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsersCount());
        for (User user : userList){
            List<Role> roleList = RoleLocalServiceUtil.findBybyUser((int)user.getUserId(), 2);
            logger.info ("list size: "+roleList.size());
        }
        personRoleList.add(roleList);
        renderRequest.setAttribute("roles", personRoleList);
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
}
```

In the log I see `list size: 0` all the time. What am I missing? how should I access finder method in order to obtain results? running query in `SQL` with `where user_id= 1 and status_id =2` return result

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Where is your `service.xml` located? Is it in your custom portlet or you want to modify liferay's `service.xml`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [***Delete record on sepecific field value in liferay service builder***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559048/delete-record-on-sepecific-field-value-in-liferay-service-builder)