# Delete record on sepecific field value in liferay service builder

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-service-builder

I want to delete specific record using Field Name

Table : Dummy Entity

- Field Id
- Field Name

  ```
  public void deleteLocation(req, res){
  String getLocationName = request.getParameter("locationName");
  Location locationToDelete = new LocationImpl();
  locationToDelete.setLocationName(getLocationName);
  LocationLocalServiceUtil.deleteLocation(locationToDelete);
  }
  ```

It's not showing me any error but the record doesn't get deleted. Please hep me out.

Comment: Well, you can achieve this by adding `finder` node for that specific field in your `service.xml`. On successful build, it will add CRUD operation in your service based on that column.

Comment: Elaborate your question further. What is your field `name` and what sort of `value` does it accept? Also, specify the entity name so that I may sum up changes.

Comment: `Name` field is `String` type?

Comment: @ParkashKumar :  Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to add `<finder>` node for that specific field in `service.xml`, as following  (saying `Location` is your entity name, `name` is your field name and `Name` is the name of finder entry in `service.xml`) and build service:

```
<column name="name" type="String" />

<finder name="Name" return-type="Collection">
    <finder-column name="name" />
</finder>
```

On successful build, it will create CRUD operations in your service based on that column. Now you can find following methods in your `LocationUtil.java`:

```
findByName,
removeByName,
countByName,
```

Create following (new) method in `LocationLocalServiceImpl.java`:

```
public void deleteLocationsByName(String name){
    try{
        LocationUtil.removeByName(name);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        // log your exception
    }
}
```

Again, on building service, this method will be available for use in your action class from `LocationLocalServiceUtil.java`, where you can call it like:

```
public void deleteLocation(req, res){
    String locationName = request.getParameter("locationName");
    LocationLocalServiceUtil.deleteLocationsByName(locationName);
}
```

That's it, you have added custom finder method to your service.

Comment: @Vinita Shah, Other way is [***CUSTOM SQL QUERIES***](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/developing-custom-sql-queries) as answered by joaco1977

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove an element by id, you can do it by the "LocalServiceUtil.delete(id)"
If you want to remove an elements by other field than id, you need to do a custom Query for that, you can search in the portal soruce for the file: portal.xml  containing this example:

```
<sql id="com.liferay.portal.service.impl.ResourceBlockLocalServiceImpl.deleteResourceBlock">
        <![CDATA[
            DELETE FROM
                ResourceBlock
            WHERE
                (referenceCount <= 0) AND
                (resourceBlockId = ?)
        ]]>
    </sql>
```

You can see here how to implement a custom query:

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/developing-custom-sql-queries